# Show result of an asynchronous call in a SwiftUI view

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, swiftui

How can I show the result of something that comes out of an asynchronous call in a SwiftUI view. In the following code, I would like to have a Text that shows the success result of the call to addressFor(location).

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var location: CLLocation
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
        // How can I have a Text here that shows the success result of the completion coming from addressFor(location)
    }
    
    private func addressFor(_ location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
        let geocoder: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placeMark, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let firstPlaceMark = placeMark?.first {
                    completion(.success(firstPlaceMark.name ?? "" + " - " + (firstPlaceMark.locality ?? "")))
                }
            } else {
                completion(.failure(error!))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(location: CLLocation(latitude: 39.8333333, longitude: -98.585522))
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a Publisher and subscribe to it.

Comment: Yes, I read about the concept of Publisher and Subscriber in Combine, and I am new to it. So if you could help me figure out how to make a Publisher and Subscriber in my example above, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Sorry but it’s unclear what you want to do. None of your code calls your function so what would call it? The usual thing is to maintain an ObservableObject but even then I do not know when you want to perform geocoding.

Comment: var location: CLLocation is passed to this view, just like ContentView(location: CLLocation(latitude: 39.8333333, longitude: -98.585522)). I want a Text in place of    Text("Hello, World!") that shows the result of passing that location in addressFor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I told you in comments, I'd use an observable object and subscribe to a property of it:

```
class Geocoder : ObservableObject {
    @Published var address = "Hello World"
    func addressFor(_ location: CLLocation) -> Void {
        let geocoder: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placeMark, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let firstPlaceMark = placeMark?.first {
                    self.address = (firstPlaceMark.name ?? "") + " " + (firstPlaceMark.locality ?? "")
                }
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    init(location: CLLocation) {
        self.location = location
        self.geocoder.addressFor(location)
    }
    var location: CLLocation
    @ObservedObject var geocoder = Geocoder()
    var body: some View {
        Text(geocoder.address)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
@State private var name: String?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .onAppear {
                addressFor(location) { result in
                    let value = try? result.get()
                    self.name = value ?? "unknown"
                }
            }
        if name != nil {
            Text("Result: \(name!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer works as well. Unfortunately, I can only accept one as the answer. But thanks a lot again for your solution.